# Kafka : how to delete all messages in a queue that I have no access?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka message queue and I am no access to `bin` folder of kafka installation.

Is it possible to delete all messages in my queue in this case ? Is it enough to create a client and just consume all messages ?

Comment: Depends on the retention policy of the broker/queue. But no, generally Kafka is a persistent message bus so consuming the messages won’t remove them from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

No, consuming messages won't empty the topic.

You can use the AdminClient API to modify the topic retention size to a small value, then increase it back

Or you can download the Kafka binaries on a machine you do have access to, and do the same; you don't need access to the actual bin directory where Kafka is running